# Cannot access child's state inside callback handler triggered from parent. (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a live example. The counter stays static, won't be incremented.
https://codepen.io/tudou/pen/jQeYaM

I use `ParentModal` as model layout which has title, footer (common shared components) and left implementation in `ChildModalForUserForm`.

However, when user click submit button from `ParentModal` which triggers handler defined in `ChildModalForUserForm`.

In `submitHandler`, I could not access states variables. How could I fix this?

```
const ParentModal = (props) => {
    const {name, primaryButtonHandler} = props;
    return  ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <>
            ~~~
            <button type="submit" onClick={primaryButtonHandler}>
        </>, document.body
    ) ;
}

export default ParentModal;
```

```
const ChildModalForUserForm = ({user}) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState(user?.name)
    const [title, setTitle] = useState(user?.title)
    const submitHandler = (e) =>{
         // process form data and fire request.
        // however, not able to access title state here.
        // but setTitle is acceessible
    }

    return (
        <>
            <ParentModal
                name={`hello world`}
                primaryButtonHandler={submitHandler}
            >
                ~~~~~
            </ParentModal>
        </>
    )
}

export default ChildModalForUserForm;
```

Comment: Few things: a child component is the component that sits inside another component `<A> <B /> </A>` in this case `B` is a child and `A` is a parent. Secondly, you do not have to specify `React.Fragment`. for some time now you can simply use `<> </>`. and about the submit button, on the `onClick` you execute `setParentModalToggle` method that you get from `props`. but inside `ChildModalForUserForm` you never pass such property down to `ParentModal`. you only pass in `primaryButtonHandler` and `name`. So `setParentModalToggle` is undefined

Comment: @Lith Thank you! primaryButtonHandler is defined in this child, why should it pass values to the parent ParentModal?

Comment: You should be able to access name inside the submitHandler. Could it be the case that user is coming in asynchronously and therefore initial value of the name is undefined, maybe wrap your submitHandler with a useCallback where name is in the dependency array?

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu updated the post. Are you saying i could access name but not title? It's sync call ..... Or is there a better pattern for me case? thanks!

Comment: Technically you should be able to reach any variable in the component’s scope, it’s hard to pinpoint the issue without a MRE.

Comment: @BerkKurkcuoglu shorturl.at/awxE0

Comment: In your codepen everything works as expected, I couldn't understand the issue, the counter is increasing as it should.